# Ocultar coisas de paginas do blogger

Tags: blogger

Estou criando um template para o blogger e gostaria de saber como esconder algumas `divs` e `widget` de outras paginas, por exemplo:
Não mostrar a `<div...>` na pagina inicial, apenas na pagina de um post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No blogger você pode definir condições usando `<b:if cond='SUA-CONDIÇÃO-AQUI'>` você pode ver as [Tags de dados para layouts aqui](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=pt-BR)

### Exibir em paginas especificas

**Exibir na pagina inicial:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>`

---

**Exibir em pagina de marcadores, arquivos e na pagina inicial:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != "item"'>`

---

**Exibir nas paginas das postagens:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>`

---

**Exibir em paginas estáticas:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>`

---

**Exibir apenas em um url especifico:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "COLE-A-URL-AQUI"'>`

---

**Exibir apenas em paginas de arquivos:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "archive"'>`

---

### Para ocultar os elementos use os seguintes

**Ocultar em paginas estáticas:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != "static_page"'>`

---

**Ocultar o elemento em pagina de postagem:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != "item"'>`

---

**Ocultar da pagina de marcadores, página inicial e arquivo:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>`

---

**Ocultar o elemento na pagina inicial use:**
`<b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl != data:blog.url'>`

> **Como usar:**
>   Vá para: **Tema** > **Editar HTML** > Encontre o elemento que você quer ocultar > Cole a condição desejada no inicio do elemento `<b:if cond='??????'><div...>` e o fechamento `</b:if>` no fim do elemento, exemplo `</div></b:if>` > Clique em **Salvar Tema**